# 13 digits number get exponential format when import using Feeds module from JSON

Tags: mysql, json, drupal, feed

I am using Drupal to import feeds using [Feeds](http://drupal.org/project/feeds) module and [feeds_jsonpath_parser](http://drupal.org/project/feeds_jsonpath_parser)
I import a 13 digits integer into a text field (should be enought)
When i do the batch, i notice that 1280212824001 is written 1.280212824E+12 in the database.
While when i add it manually it goes well.

Any idea what might be causing this ?

Comment: Would be a good idea to convert the number to a string before importing. But its provided as a number in the JSON file.

Comment: I have noticed that the JSON object is parsed using json_decode, after this decode, numbers are exponential.

Comment: **SOLUTION**: http://batayneh.me/post/parse-json-objects-numbers-string

Answer (score 0):

Alternative of using [casting in mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast) :-

[How to compare scientific notation and decimal numbers in mysql MIN() aggregate function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8356104/how-to-compare-scientific-notation-and-decimal-numbers-in-mysql-min-aggregate/8359351#8359351)